# XO game in ASP.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm currently writing an XO game with c# and having a problem.
the XO table is a collection of asp buttons, i wanted to write a function that puts X or O value in each button - and it needs to be dynamic. how am i supposed to write such function ??
this is an example of what i did so far.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            turndisplay.Visible = true;


            Session["p1"] = player1;
            Session["p2"] = player2;
            player1.setsymbol("X");
            player2.setsymbol("O");

            //Button1.Click += Button1_Click;
            //Button2.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button3.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button4.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button5.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button6.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button7.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button8.Click += Button_Click;
            //Button9.Click += Button_Click;
        }

        if (turn == 0)
        {
            turndisplay.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
        }
        else
        {
            turndisplay.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
        }

    }

    public void pushthebutton() // currently effects only on button 1 !
    {
    if (turn == 0)
    {
                player1.setsymbol("X");
                Button1.Text = (Session["p1"]as Player).getsymbol();
                turndisplay.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                player2.setsymbol("O");
                Button1.Text = player2.getsymbol();
                turndisplay.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 0;
            }

        }


    protected void Button1_Click(Button sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1.Text == " ")
        {
            pushthebutton();
            gamecheck();
        }
    }
```

how can i effect every button that the player would like, without writing it 9 times ?

after edit *** so you say .. change the (object sender) to (Button sender) ?? but my function pushtebutton know only Button1.Text

Comment: @WilliamCustode has the answer for you.  Make one method for the button click event - and assign that method to each of the buttons `OnClick` event.  You will need to cast the `sender` to a `Button` type and then you can get the `Text` property - `Button btn = sender as Button; if (btn != null) { if (btn.Text == " ") { } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William's answer is the correct approach.  You don't need to have an individual method for each button - some or all of the buttons can use the same method.

So say you have this method:

```
protected void Button_Click(Button sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button btn = sender as Button;

    if (btn != null)
    {
        if (btn.Text == " ")
        {
            pushthebutton();
            gamecheck();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses the [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to convert the sender object to a `Button`.  If the conversion is unsuccessful, `btn` will be null, hence the `if` check.  Otherwise, the conversion was successful and you can check the `Text` property.

In your page load, you'd simply assign the `Button_Click` method above to each of your buttons:

```
Button1.Click += Button_Click;
Button2.Click += Button_Click;
Button3.Click += Button_Click;
Button4.Click += Button_Click;
Button5.Click += Button_Click;
Button6.Click += Button_Click;
Button7.Click += Button_Click;
Button8.Click += Button_Click;
Button9.Click += Button_Click;
```

Comment: yes i got the idea .. instead of 9 button click events create just one that can effect every button in the page?

Comment: @user3209554 - Yep, you got it exactly.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Write it once and hook it up in the `Page_Load` like so:

```
Button1.Click += Button_Click;
Button2.Click += Button_Click;
Button3.Click += Button_Click;
// etc...
```

Comment: so write it from 1 to 9 inside the page load and put Button_Click inside the function ??

Comment: No, you leave one of the Button#_Click methods as is, and rename it from, say, Button1_Click to Button_Click. Then write from 1-9 inside your Page_Load.

Comment: its not working , i changed the methods name to be all the same (Button_Click) ??? and wrote the three lines above, inside my page load but it makes syntax error

Comment: The `sender` parameter in the `Button_Click` method corresponds to the button that was clicked. Change the method so that it casts the `sender` to a `Button`, then read the text out of it.